# How to hibernate validate optional values?

Tags: java, regex, hibernate, hibernate-validator

How can I create a hibernate validation annotation that a value should follow my following rule:

```
//should be: either empty, or if it has a value, it sould only be "A" or "B"
@Pattern(regex = "???")
String value;
```

Comment: If it is something specific you should implement your own constraint http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html/validator-customconstraints.html